# Input redirection on command line to java program does not work for Console class

Tags: java, command-line

Java version = 14.0.1

OS = Windows 8

The 2 methods f1 and f2 in the code work the same way when I just simply run `java Test` for each separate compilation.

But when I redirect input from a file on the command line, as in `java Test < script.txt`, only f1 works and f2 gives me the "no console" error.
Why so?

f2 even fails when I call it within jshell by Test.f2(), whereas f1() simply works.

I was familiar with f1 type of code. I started using f2 type of code today. While making f2 I thought there was some error in my program or system, and was gonna give up until I thought of trying f1 and realized my program was okay.

What am I doing wrong in f2?

Java Code...

```
import java.io.*;

class Test{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        //f1(); //OR
        f2();
    }
    
    
    static void f1() throws Exception{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s = null;
        int i =0 ;
        
        while(true){
            System.out.println("s = ?");
            s = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(i + " : " + s);
            i++;
            if(s.equals("exit"))break;
        }
        
    }
    
    //redirection does not work on this
    public static void f2(){
        Console console = System.console();
        if(console==null){
            System.out.println("ERROR: no Console instance");
            return;
        }
        String s = null;
        int i =0 ;
        
        while(true){
            console.printf("s = ?\n");
            s = console.readLine();
            
            console.printf("%d = %s\n",i,s);
            i++;
            if(s.equals("exit"))break;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample wannabe Script... script.txt

```
this
will
print
exit
this
wont
print
```

Comment: I don't think that java.io.Console will work here. Quoting from https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Console.html: *"If the virtual machine is started from an interactive command line without redirecting the standard input and output streams then its console will exist and will typically be connected to the keyboard and display from which the virtual machine was launched. If the virtual machine is started automatically, for example by a background job scheduler, then it will typically not have a console. "* Hope this helps

Comment: user79161 - okay. i guess i will stick to the older classes; or not use redirection with the newer Console class; and take the script file name as explicit argument.
Thank you.